# ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of... on MODIFY COLUMN

Tags: mysql, alter

I have a `tb_denunciation` with a `denouncer_id int(10) unsigned` column with a foreign key referencing the `tb_user(user_id)`.

I need to add NOT NULL to the `denouncer_id`. I already checked that there are no null values in this column and (of course, there's a foreign key) all `denouncer_id` values match to some `user_id` on the `tb_user`.

I'm running this command:

```
ALTER TABLE tb_denunciation MODIFY denouncer_id int(10) unsigned not null;
```

And I get the error:

> ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of
>   './my_db_schema/#sql-1153_1b4133' to './my_db_schema/tb_denunciation'
>   (errno: 150)

I've googled that this error is related do foreign keys, but all I could check is ok. Whats wrong?

Comment: Foreign key columns should be the same in parent and child table. Drop the constraint, then alter both tables, then add back the constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to first remove the foreign key, and then do the column altering. Then you may add back the foreign key again after it's altered.

Comment: That worked and made me find my mistake. The foreign key of denouncer_id had an "ON DELETE SET NULL". How could i set a column NOT NULL with a foreign key like this??? =/